# Why can I compile and use std::cout << std::chrono::year_month_day data type on Windows, but in VS Code on macOS I can't compile?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, c++20

My problem is pretty straight forward I think but please forgive me if I suck at explaining still. Basically I am learning C++ and playing around with `<chrono>` from C++20 to store date values in a simple Person class. The problem is this source code on my M1 MacBook Pro using VS Code with standard set to C++20, it throws me a red squiggly under the << after std::cout and before yearMonthDay in this line of code `std::cout << yearMonthDay << std::endl;` Using clang++ in the terminal to build, I get this error `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::__1::chrono::year_month_day')` However, on my Windows workstation in Visual Studio 2019, this code satisfies intellisense fine, compiles and links successfully and outputs the year month and day I set as expected.

Why does this code work on Visual Studio 2019 in Windows, but not VS Code and clang++ on macOS (M1 MacBook Pro)? I have set the standard to c++20 in VS Code and clang++ at the command line.

Here is the source code for reference. The problem is this line in main.cpp `std::cout << yearMonthDay << std::endl;`

Thank you!

**main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include "person.h"

int main()
{
    Person p1;

    p1.setBirthDay(std::chrono::day{4});
    p1.setBirthMonth(std::chrono::month{12});
    p1.setBirthYear(std::chrono::year{1996});

    auto yearMonthDay = p1.getBirthdate();

    std::cout << p1.getFullName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p1.getAge() << std::endl;
    std::cout << yearMonthDay << std::endl;

    p1.setAge(29);
    p1.setfName("John");
    p1.setlName("Conner");

    std::cout << p1.getAge() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p1.getFullName() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**person.cpp**

```
#include "person.h"

std::chrono::year_month_day Person::getBirthdate()
{
    auto ymd{Person::birthYear / Person::birthMonth / Person::birthDay};
    return ymd;
}

void Person::setBirthDay(std::chrono::day d)
{
    Person::birthDay = d;
}

void Person::setBirthMonth(std::chrono::month m)
{
    Person::birthMonth = m;
}

void Person::setBirthYear(std::chrono::year y)
{
    Person::birthYear = y;
}

void Person::setfName(std::string fname)
{
    Person::fName = fname;
}

void Person::setlName(std::string lname)
{
    Person::lName = lname;
}

std::string Person::getFullName()
{
    return Person::fName + " " + Person::lName;
}

void Person::setAge(int x)
{
    Person::age = x;
}

int Person::getAge() const
{
    return Person::age;
}
```

**person.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    std::string fName;
    std::string lName;
    std::chrono::day birthDay;
    std::chrono::month birthMonth;
    std::chrono::year birthYear;

public:
    Person()
    {
        Person::fName = "NULL";
        Person::lName = "NULL";
        Person::age = 0;
        Person::birthDay = {std::chrono::day(0)};
        Person::birthMonth = {std::chrono::month(0)};
        Person::birthYear = {std::chrono::year(0)};
    }

    ~Person()
    {
        std::cout << "Deconstructed."
                  << "\n";
    }

    std::string getFullName();
    std::chrono::year_month_day getBirthdate();
    void setBirthDay(std::chrono::day d);
    void setBirthMonth(std::chrono::month m);
    void setBirthYear(std::chrono::year y);
    void setfName(std::string fname);
    void setlName(std::string lname);
    void setAge(int x);
    int getAge() const;
};
```

Comment: C++20 is pretty new.  When was the last time you updated your compiler?  What version do you have?

Comment: This is the problem with `auto`, you never know exactly what you're getting.

Comment: I tried and it still spits this error "main.cpp:17:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::__1::chrono::year_month_day')
    std::cout << yearMonthDay << std::endl;"

Comment: I have Xcode tools updated to the latest it can go. Whatever Apples arbitrary clang version number is. I think 12.05

Comment: I have also tried not using auto and explicitly typing std::chrono::year_month_day but it still doesn't like it. It specifically seems to not be liking the year_month_day data type.

Comment: As with many questions about new features, this is your best friend: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support.

Comment: Can't seem to find the exact feature set under C++20 it would be but I am guessing it has to do with clang and Apple's compiler. Plus 20 is still new etc.. Oh well, no big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libc++ (the clang std::lib) isn't yet shipping this part of C++20.  However if you would like to use a transition tool, there exists an [open-source preview of this part of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

For the parts you're using in this example, the preview is in `date.h`, which is header only.  Just `#include "date/date.h"`, and point the compiler at `date/include`.  Also the namespace is different.  Substitute `date::` for `std::chrono::` for things like `year_month_day`.  And to get the streaming operators to work you'll need:

```
using date::operator<<;
```

so that the streaming operators will be found in `namespace date`.